# Tablesorter - filter functions on empty cells

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the tablesorter 2.7.9 (Mottie's fork) with the filter functions widget and I'd like to have the built-in select droplist be able to select empty cell values as a filter option.  Does anyone know an easy way to do this aside from putting fake values in all the empty cells?  Already my filter droplist contains 2 blank options:  one for deselecting the filter and one to match the data value from my table, but of course setting it to this just deselects the filter.

Comment: Let us see some code. Please give us a JSFiddle to better help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly there isn't an easy way to select empty cells with the way the filter widget is written. The main problem is how do we differentiate between clearing the filter and searching for empty table cells?

I could add some way to specifically find empty table cells, or as you said add "fake" values into the empty table cells - one way is to add `<span style="display:none">{empty}</span>` inside of empty cells. Then the select dropdown would include an `{empty}` entry so users know what they are selecting ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/417/)).

Would that work for you?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'll use the fake values for now.  I didn't think to add a hidden span.  Since the empty value gets added to the filter droplist a second time, users think empty should be selectable.   I'd think an enhancement that either removes this extra value (or better) adds some kind of hardcoded empty match string to the option value would be great!

Comment: As of v2.21.5, you can use an alternative method that doesn't require modifying the HTML - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29506523/145346

Answer (score 2):

You can search for an empty string using regex

```
var filters = [],
col = <insertColumnNumberHere>, // the column number to perform the search on
txt = "/^$/"; // ^$ = empty string
filters[col] = txt;
$.tablesorter.setFilters($('table'), filters, true);
```

With the knowledge of the empty string regex you should be able to create a droplist where one of the blank options has a value of `"/^$/"`.

Answer (score 0):

An incomplete solution is to simply sort ascending or descending to group all the empty.  That suits my needs as I'm wanting the "not empty cells".