# Is there a way in tablesorter to filter to select only rows where the field is empty?

Tags: filter, tablesorter

When I use '|Empty' in `filter_functions` no filtering is applied. I'd like to be able filter so that rows where the field is empty are shown.

Comment: Possibly related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14990971/145346

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just updated the [tablesorter fork](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) repository, so with v2.21.5+, you can now add a `filter_function` to target empty cells, and use the `filter_selectSource` to populate the select with custom and/or all column cell text as options ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/117/)):

```js
$(function(){
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                0: {
                    '{empty}' : function (e, n, f, i, $r, c) {
                        return $.trim(e) === '';
                    }
                }
            },
            filter_selectSource: {
                0: function (table, column, onlyAvail) {
                    // get an array of all table cell contents for a table column
                    var array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);
                    // include the filter_function option
                    array.push('{empty}');
                    return array;
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Mottie. I've tried your approach above. It works fine. However, this works only when the select source function is static.
The select source function was not get invoked as expected when `table.trigger('update')`.

select source function can be dynamically invoked by `table.trigger('update')` if I do below:

```
filter_functions: {
  0: true
}
```

Comment: it seems I have to call $.tablesorter.filter.buildSelect() specifically to update the dropdown lists