# Can tablesorter filter by null?

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

This may be an odd question, but I'm using TableSorter and the Filter widget and I'm being asked if I can filter by a "blank" (in other words, nothing in the filter box at all.) I cannot imagine how that would work, but I thought I would ask in case someone has a suggestion. I'm assuming this would be just to detect if there is a presence of any character at all in that column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/29482927/145346