# Data attribute for (Mottie) Tablesorter filter_selectSource

Tags: tablesorter

I have a dynamic table which can contain a `status` column that can contain a predefined list of status, for example:

```
0: closed
1: Open
2: Pending
3: ...
```

The status label is displayed in the table, but the `id` number is used for actual filtering. I successfully applied tablesorter `filter-select` to display a select filter, but it either display label (won't filter) or `id` (not pretty).

I could fix this using `filter_selectSource` inside javascript, but since my table is dynamic and displayed using *Handlebar*, I'm looking for an html solution using data attributes.

Is there a data attribute that could be used to set the filter select label/value, similar to how `data-text` can be used to define unparsed text? Or is there a way to define a custom parser for filter that would return a label/value combo as an array for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Mottie reply and `tablesorter.filter.getOptions` source, I came up with this. Adding the `filter-metaselect` class to my column(s) `th` enables the `data-value` attribute in the cell `td` to be used as the select options. The parsed/unparsed text can still be used. Note that the child part of `getOptions` has been omitted since I'm not using feature at the moment.

Table Cell :

```
<td data-value="1">
  Projet actif
</td>
```

Select option :

```
<option value="1" parsed="projet actif" data-function-name="1">Projet actif</option>
```

Javascript:

```
filter_selectSource: {
    ".filter-metaselect": function (table, column, onlyAvail) {
        table = $( table )[0];
        var rowIndex, tbodyIndex, len, row, cache, indx, child, childLen, colData,
            c = table.config,
            wo = c.widgetOptions,
            arry = [];
        for ( tbodyIndex = 0; tbodyIndex < c.$tbodies.length; tbodyIndex++ ) {
            cache = c.cache[tbodyIndex];
            len = c.cache[tbodyIndex].normalized.length;
            // loop through the rows
            for ( rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < len; rowIndex++ ) {
                // get cached row from cache.row ( old ) or row data object
                // ( new; last item in normalized array )
                row = cache.row ?
                    cache.row[ rowIndex ] :
                    cache.normalized[ rowIndex ][ c.columns ].$row[0];
                // check if has class filtered
                if ( onlyAvail && row.className.match( wo.filter_filteredRow ) ) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Get the column data attributes
                if (row.getElementsByTagName('td')[column].getAttribute('data-value')) {
                    colData = row.getElementsByTagName('td')[column].getAttribute('data-value');
                } else {
                    colData = false;
                }

                // get non-normalized cell content
                if ( wo.filter_useParsedData ||
                    c.parsers[column].parsed ||
                    c.$headerIndexed[column].hasClass( 'filter-parsed' ) ) {

                    arry[ arry.length ] = {
                        value : (colData) ? colData : cache.normalized[ rowIndex ][ column ],
                        text : cache.normalized[ rowIndex ][ column ]
                    };

                    // child row parsed data
                    /* TODO */
                } else {

                    arry[ arry.length ] = {
                        value : (colData) ? colData : cache.normalized[ rowIndex ][ c.columns ].raw[ column ],
                        text : cache.normalized[ rowIndex ][ c.columns ].raw[ column ]
                    };

                    // child row unparsed data
                    /* TODO */
                }
            }
        }

        // Remove duplicates in `arry` since using an array of objects
        // won't do it automatically
        var arr = {};

        for ( var i=0, len=arry.length; i < len; i++ )
            arr[arry[i]['text']] = arry[i];

        arry = new Array();
        for ( var key in arr )
            arry.push(arr[key]);

        return arry;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`filter_selectSource` documentation](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-filter-selectsource) has an example where this widget option calls the [`filter.getOptions`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#function-getoptions) which returns an array of cell text or parsed values (based on the filter parser setting); if that doesn't return the values you want, grab the values yourself and return an array in that function.

Here is a basic example of how to use it: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/117/ (related to [Is there a way in tablesorter to filter to select only rows where the field is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29482927/145346))

```
$(function(){
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
        widgetOptions: {
            filter_functions: {
                0: {
                    '{empty}' : function (e, n, f, i, $r, c) {
                        return $.trim(e) === '';
                    }
                }
            },
            filter_selectSource: {
                0: function (table, column, onlyAvail) {
                    // get an array of all table cell contents for a table column
                    var array = $.tablesorter.filter.getOptions(table, column, onlyAvail);
                    // manipulate the array as desired, then return it
                    array.push('{empty}');
                    return array;
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: It's not _exactly_ what I'm looking for, but it gave me an idea how to do it. In both `filter_` options, you can set the query selector for the `th` element instead of the col identifier? It won't crash if the selector can't be found ? Or if there's two or more columns with the same selector ?

Comment: You can use a css selector instead of the column index, e.g. `filter_selectSource: { '.foo' : function() { ... } }`, if that is what you mean.

Comment: https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/widgets/widget-filter.js#L1627